# migrating existing legacy laravel application in react frontend

Tags: reactjs, laravel, migration, html-parsing

We have an existing legacy laravel application and like to convert it into a react application for this kind of application we want to migrate but can't do in a big bang way. what is Ideally needed? make a react application and put laravel application in an iframe and then migrate one by one section? thinking of using httpclient and parse dom.

do we have a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly you need to actually analyze the scope of work that needs to happen.

Ideally, you migrate component of your Laravel app step by step to React app.